# Number of non-congruent quadrilaterals with vertices chosen from among seven points equally distributed on a circle

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, quadrilateral

*Seven points are equally distributed on a circle. How many non-congruent quadrilaterals can be drawn with vertices chosen from among the seven points?*

**My approach:**

If there are $7$ points and we have to choose 4 points then there are $\binom{7}{4}$ ways to construct a quadrilateral.

Hence, there are a total of $35$ ways in a circle to construct a quadrilateral using $7$ points. But these $35$ quadrilaterals include both congruent and non-congruent quadrilaterals. From this how can we find no of non-congruent quadrilaterals?

Also, I am unclear about the concept of non-congruent and congruent quadrilaterals. So please help me understand this with your clear explanation.

Comment: With four points you'll always choose two adjacent points. Make a sketch of all the different quadrilaterals having a fixed side in common.

Comment: Are you only counting simple quadrilaterals, or also self-crossing quadrilaterals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two quadrilaterals to be congruent, corresponding sides and angles must be equal.

Because of the symmetric arrangement of points in this case, if corresponding sides are equal, angles would be too. So focusing only on corresponding sides, here's what we can do.

We'll take side lengths as one more than the (smaller) number of points lying between its two ends. Meaning sides involving adjacent points have a length of $1$ unit. If a side is obtained by skipping one point, it's length is $2$ units.$^{[1]}$

Now, if $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, and $x_4$ are the side-lengths, we have $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 7$, $x_i$ is a natural number.$^{[2]}$ The number of unique solutions to this equation would be

$$\binom{7-1}{4-1} = 20$$

Rotations of one unique type of quadrilateral correspond to $4$ solutions counted in the result we got above ($20$). For example,

$$(1, 2, 1, 3), \; (3, 1, 2, 1), \; (1, 3, 1, 2), \; (2, 1, 3, 1)$$

Dividing by $4$ would compensate for that. We will have $20/4 = 5$ potential side length tuples.$^{[3]}$

However, we also have the problem of reflections. And I do not have a simple/elegant way to address that.

The good things is $5$ is not too big a number. So, let's list the $5$ solutions and remove any that are extras (reflections).

$$\begin{align*}
(1, 1, 1, 4) \\
(1, 1, 2, 3) \\
(1, 1, 3, 2) \\
(1, 2, 1, 3) \\
(2, 2, 2, 1) \\
\end{align*}$$

Of the five above, (1, 1, 2, 3) and (1, 1, 3, 2) are the only cases of reflections. Others are fine. So counting only one of the two and ignoring another, we get our answer - $4$ non-congruent quadrilaterals.

Thanks to ***joriki*** for pointing out the error in the tentative solution I started with, and helping me see the way forward.

---

**Footnotes**

$^{[1]}$ We can get away with this because we are not concerned with the actual side lengths, only whether $2$ sides are equal. And because the points are equally distributed, sides spanning equal number of points must be equal.

It's also important to understand that under our system of measurement a side length of $2$ is not necessarily double the side length of $1$ under other systems. But again, we don't care about that.

$^{[2]}$ The sum of the number of points spanned by the fours sides must be equal to the total number of points on the circle, $7$.

$^{[3]}$ Any solution of the form $(a, b, a, b)$ won't give $4$ quadrilaterals but only $2$ (or $1$ if $a = b$). Thankfully, no such solutions exist in this case ($7$ isn't an even number).

Comment: Congruence also includes reflections, so the four length tuples $(1,1,2,3)$, $(3,1,1,2)$, $(2,3,1,1)$, $(1,2,3,1)$ and their mirror images all describe the same type of quadrilateral. The answer is nevertheless $4$, since you should have calculated $20/4=5$ instead of $20/5=4$. The $4$ different quadrilaterals are $(1,2,1,3)$, $(1,1,2,3)$, $(1,2,2,2)$ and $(1,1,1,4)$.

Comment: Oh thank you! Any suggestions on how to account for the reflections? Or do we just need to list the $5$ potential solutions and brute force it from there?

Comment: I would have taken the approach in Mike Earnest’s answer; that’s the usual systematic way of accounting for all symmetries. You could apply that to your side length tuples, too: Arrange them in a square. There are $20$ tuples; the identity leaves all $20$ invariant; rotations and horizontal or vertical reflections leave none invariant; but a diagonal reflection (of which there are $2$) leaves $6$ invariant, for a total of $20+2\cdot6=32$ fixed points for $8$ symmetries; so there are $\frac{32}8=4$ equivalence classes.

Comment: Greatly appreciate your help. I have no knowledge of abstract algebra, so I had to work with a limited understanding of what you wrote above. But it did give me the confidence to go ahead and improve my answer instead of removing it.

Comment: There are quite a number of answers on this site that use Burnside’s lemma, so if you’re interested in learning more about it, there should be plenty of examples to work with. Proving it requires some group theory, but applying it doesn’t – just list the symmetry operations, count the fixed points for each of them (i.e. how many of your objects/configurations/arrangements they leave invariant), add all those counts and divide by the number of symmetry operations; the result is the number of equivalence classes, i.e. the number of objects that are inequivalent under those symmetry operations.

Comment: Can you explain how did you write the side length between two consecutive points must be 1? and also how you wrote x1+x2+x3+x4=7?

Comment: @NOTACID Please refer to the third paragraph (just edited it) and the edited footnotes. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: I have some doubts regarding this. Can we do this in a chatroom?

Comment: Sure, if you are online now.

Comment: please invite me im not aware of creating it and I also don't meet requirement of 100 reputations

Comment: Hopefully, this would work. This is a first for me too. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/151551/non-congruent-quadrilaterals?tab=general

Answer (score 2):

This can be answered with Burnside's lemma, because counting quadrilaterals up to congruence is the same as counting the number of orbits of quadrilaterals under the symmetry group of the regular heptagon.

For each symmetry, we must add up the total number of fixed points for that symmetry, and then divide by the number of symmetries. There are 14 symmetries, consisting of 7 rotations and 7 reflections.

- The trivial rotation has $\binom74=35$ fixed points. All 6 other rotations have no fixed points.
- Each reflection has $\binom 32=3$ fixed points. A quadrilateral with reflection symmetry is uniquely specified by choosing two out of three points which are on one side of the line of symmetry, and then choosing those corresponding points on the other side.

Putting this altogether, the number of quadrilaterals up to congruence is
$$
\frac1{14}\left(35 +\color{gray}{6\cdot0}+7\cdot 3 \right)=4.
$$
Here are what the four quadrilaterals look like:

1. Four consecutive vertices.
2. Three consecutive vertices, and one non-consecutive.
3. Two pairs of consecutive vertices, such that the pairs are not adjacent to each other.
4. One pair of consecutive vertices, while the other vertices are by themselves.

Comment: How are there 14 symmetries? Explain

Comment: @NOTACID Every symmetry of a 2D shape is a combination of a translation, reflection, and/or rotation. There are no translations here. You can see there are seven possible rotations, since the heptagon must rotate by a multiple of $360^\circ/7$. You can also see there are seven possible reflections, since there are seven possible lines of reflection symmetry (one line passing through each vertex, dividing the heptagon into two equal parts). 7 + 7 = 14.